# Unityの実行ができず落ちてしまいます。

Tags: unity3d

以前までUnityプロジェクトを起動した際に出ていなかった警告が、急に
以下の警告が出るようになってしまい、

> Tiled GPU perf. warning: RenderTexture color surface  (0x0) was not
>   cleared/discarded, doing 
>   UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()

実行した場合には、以下の文が表示されUnityごと落ちてしまいます。

> The file 'MemoryStream' is corrupted! Remove it and launch unity
>   again! [Position out of bounds!]

使用しているUnityのバージョンは5.3.1です。
何か良い解決方法がありましたら教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 2):

同様のエラーメッセージが出た人の[ブログ](http://yanpen.net/2015/12/25/unitythe-file-memorystream-is-corrupted-remove-it-and-launch-unity-again/)によると、LibraryフォルダとTempフォルダを削除後、エディタを再起動したら直るようです。  
（LibraryとTempは自動生成なので消しても大丈夫とのこと）

Unity公式フォーラムの同様のエントリに寄せられた[回答](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-4-5-memory-stream-is-corrupted.248356/#post-1719534)には「プロジェクトで使ってるプレハブなどの参照先が存在しない時に発生するっぽい。存在しない参照先を[自作スクリプト](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/editor-want-to-check-all-prefabs-in-a-project-for-an-attached-monobehaviour.253149/#post-1673716)で全部抽出して、修正したら直ったよ」(意訳)と書かれています。

Comment: 早朝にもかかわらず質問のご回答をしてくださりありがとうございました。
Libraryフォルダ、Tempフォルダの両方を削除したところ実行することができました。
Unity公式フォーラムの方も是非参考にさせていただきます。